# Compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \min \left\{ e^{-\frac{\| {\bf x}\|^2}{2}}, e^{-\frac{\|{\bf x}+a {\bf 1}\|^2}{2}} \right\} d {\bf x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am somewhat stuck computing the following integral:
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \min \left\{ e^{-\frac{\| {\bf x}\|^2}{2}}, e^{-\frac{\|{\bf x}+a {\bf 1}\|^2}{2}} \right\} d {\bf x}
\end{align}
where $a>0$ and ${\bf 1}$ is a vector of all ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Rotate your coordinate system so that the integrand becomes

$$\min\left\{\exp\left(-\frac{||\mathbf{x}||^2}{2}\right),\exp\left(-\frac{||\mathbf{x}+a\sqrt{n}\mathbf{e}_n||^2}{2}\right)\right\}$$

That way the integral is split at the hyperplane $x_n = -a\sqrt{n}/2$.

---

Spoiler: The answer will be

> $$(\sqrt{2\pi})^{n}\cdot\operatorname{erfc}\left(a\sqrt{\frac{n}{8}}\right)$$